# How to add assemblies to WiX toolset setup, which comes from a nuget package?

Tags: c#, .net, wix

I use the Votive-project type to create a setup with the WiX toolset. I know, that I can add an assembly like this to the setup:

```
<File Id="FILE_myproject.dll" Source="$(var.myproject.TargetPath)" KeyPath="yes" />
```

What I don't know is, how can I add referenced assemblies to the setup, which comes in a nuget package?

In my concrete example I need to add the assemblies of the EntityFramework-package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We add each of them as a separate component with its own GUID :

```
  <Component Id="Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock.dll" Guid="{3E99B3EA-8528-4125-A8BA-B492B341479C}">
    <File Id="Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock.dll" Name="Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock.dll" Source="$(var.project.TargetDir)Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock.dll" KeyPath="yes" DiskId="1" />
  </Component>
......
  <Component Id="Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.dll" Guid="{A9809E88-A097-4FFF-B311-8CB49B1B2FC5}">
    <File Id="Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.dll" Name="Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.dll" Source="$(var.project.TargetDir)Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.dll" KeyPath="yes" DiskId="1" />
  </Component>
```